# Howto debug Winsock API calls?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, windows-7, winsock

I have a very large C++ server application on Windows (Win7). It compiles fine and runs mostly well, but sometimes IP connections fail.

My suspicion is that some calls to the Winsock API get bad parameters and not all result codes are checked properly.

Is there a way to trace all calls to the Winsock API including parameters, so I can can check them for the failing connection ? Something similar to strace on Linux maybe ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This application provides complete API call trace check this http://www.sstinc.com/winsock.html

Comment: TracePlus doesn't provide me with parameter values for some important API calls. Some are just listed as "*". Is that the demo or is TracePlus not able to track those ?

Comment: May be because of demo.. If you need free tool use http://www.apimonitor.com/?gclid=CJTEqJDhtawCFUMb6wodET9QGQ. It's free and provides api calls with value

Comment: The trial version of APIMonitor also doesn't show all parameter values, eg. paramneters to listen().

Comment: You can use our Deviare API Engine: http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/ . It has a dictionary built from the Microsoft Windows SDK with the functions parameters. If you think that we missed something just drop a line on http://forum.nektra.com and we will correct it for you. With Deviare you can build your own custom solutions and don't depend of a specific console.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're running Windows 7, you can use the [Winsock Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb892103.aspx) facility available since Vista.

Comment: Are there any tools available to make the output more readable ? tracerpt.exe produces a huge XML report that I can't really make sense of.

Comment: You should be able to trace into the event viewer, which might be more readable. See the `Using Event Viewer to Start Winsock Network Event Tracing` section in the link above.

Comment: I do get the events in the EventViewer now, thanks! But I have hundreds of events and in EventViewer they are all titled "Winsock Network Event" and you have to click on each to see what it is. This doesn't really seem suited to deal with many API calls.